# null pointer exception when calling function

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, function-call

I am getting a null pointer exception when I try to call a function.  I am able to call this function in another function without issue but when i try to call it a second function i get a null pointer.

```
public class Approvals extends SnowPortalBasePage {

    @Steps
    ApproveNewApplicationSteps tommy;

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    public void approveNewEnvironment(String envName){
        tommy.logIntoApproverAccount();     <--- throws null pointer
    }

    public void approveNewApplication(RegisterNewApplicationFormData formdata){

        benchmark b = new benchmark();
        tommy.setFormData(formdata);
        b.start("logging into approver account");
        tommy.logIntoApproverAccount();  <--- works
        b.stop();
        b.start("completing data assessment and rationalization task");
        tommy.completeDataAssessmentAndRationalizationTask();
        b.stop();
        b.start();
        tommy.completeTask();
        b.stop();
        logger.info(b.resultsSec());
    }
}
```

this is the class with the method that is being called

```
public class ApproveNewApplicationSteps {

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    private static int MAX_RETRIES = 10;
    SnowPortalBasePage JohnDoe;
    RegisterNewApplicationFormData formData;

    public void logIntoApproverAccount() {
        JohnDoe.getDriver().quit(); // close out the previous webdriver
        JohnDoe.clearBrowserCookies();
        JohnDoe.loginToSNOW(url, "testuser", "password");
        JohnDoe.getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
        JohnDoe.openUrl(url);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug through it? Is tommy null?

Comment: I cant debug through it because gradle doesnt play nice with intellij's debugger.  However, the same function call in the ApproveNewApplication() works but ApproveNewEnvironemnt() does not.